# Performing background tasks in react components with Redux

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, redux

I would like to know if there is any best option to do a time consuming network request as a background task in react component.

For example, I have to load a component where it is accessible to the user but in background i have to hit some high intensive network request for future loading and results of same has to be updated in redux store(Using react-redux). It would be really helpful if someone share some ideas on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web worker is your friend

Comment: This is standard react-redux async action pattern or you can use redux's middleware or redux-saga if it is a side-effect of another action

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Currently i am checking with redux thunk and hope it will help me. @Dummy -user1095118

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to create action creators that will perform any task, regardless of sync or async and update the store accordingly. Redux-thunk is the middleware that can help you to achieve this.

https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: Thanks i am playing with redux thunk only and hope it would help me.

Comment: Cool if you need any help just comment :)